# Potts Model: the critical temperature from a free energy - in general

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function, spin-models

In describing the Three-State potts model with mean field theory, I've arrived at the following Helmholtz free energy for my system:
$$
F = \frac{1}{2} J N z m^{2} - N k T \mathrm{ln}\left( \exp\left[ \tfrac{J m}{kT} \right] + 2 \exp\left[ - \tfrac{J m}{2kT} \right] \right)
$$

Upon expanding this (for small $m$) the above becomes roughly:
$$
F \approx \mathrm{constant} + \mathrm{constant} \cdot m^{2} - \mathrm{constant} \cdot m^{3} + \mathcal{O}(m^{4})
$$

The presence of the the $m^{3}$-term indicates a first-order phase transition.

$\ $

Supposedly, there is a way to show $without\ using\ Landau\ theory$ that the critical temperature $T_{c} = \frac{Jz}{k} \frac{1}{8 \mathrm{ln}(2/3)}$ (and that there is a discontinuity in $m$ of size $\frac{1}{2}$).

How would I be able to show this? I was able to derive a self-consistency equation for $m$ which has the following form:
$$
m \ = \ \frac{ \exp( \frac{3Jm}{2kT} ) - 1 }{ \exp( \frac{3Jm}{2kT} ) + 2 }
$$

But since I'm not supposed to use Landau theory, I'm assuming that I cannot use this equation.

How can I approach this problem?

EDIT: For those curious, this pertaining to Problem 7 in [this](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/omg4.pdf) assignment set from David Tong's Statistical Mechanics course